# Janus WebRTC CentOS

Tags: centos, webrtc, janus-gateway

I'm trying to install Janus Gateway in CentOS 6.7 but I can't install dependency sofia-sip, and I have other problems like the requested glib and libssl are greater than my versions.
My questions are:

1. It's possible to install Janus in CentOS? or just have to overcome the problems of dependencies.
2. If is not possible, do you know any good any good webrtc media server solution for CentOS?

Answer (score 0):

Centos is not compatible with janus-gateway. There is an issue with glib.
Better use a new version of ubuntu-server (working well for me) of fedora server